# RAID-6 write I/O degrades over time

Tags: linux, performance, hardware-raid, raid6

I've setup a Linux system with RAID-6. Sequential write I/O performance is initially around 600 MiB/s after a reboot, but degrades to between 0.5 MiB/s and 2 MiB/s after the system has been used for a while. I'm using `sysbench` to benchmark the I/O peformance.

I'm running Gentoo Linux with kernel version 4.19.72. The RAID controller is a *Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID Tri-Mode SAS3508* using the `megraraid_sas` driver. It's configured with 5 *Seagate ST600MM0069* drives. RAID strip size is 256 K according to `perccli`. Drives are formatted with `ext4` using the `stride=64` and `stripe_width=320` options. Writeback and caching are enabled.

This is a new system. I had the same problem with an older previous system. It was also configured with RAID-6, but the system wasn't really being used so the issue was never noticed. It was repurposed a little while ago and the issue was noticed once usage increased.

The older system is using a *Broadcom / LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078* RAID controller configured with 6 *Western Digital WD1002FAEX-00Z3A* drives.

**Update**

I've reconfigured the server with RAID-5. I also realized that `stripe_width=320` was the incorrect value for the number of disks I'm using. I've corrected that to `strip_width=384`. The issue still remains. It seems to not be specific to RAID. I suspected RAID-6 because we have other, older, systems running RAID-5 that we don't have any problem with.

Comment: I'm confused - where are you doing RAID at?  The way I'm reading your question it seems like you are using both hardware RAID and also software RAID.

Comment: Please, provide more detailed info. How many disks, how they are connected, how this looks in the OS (`cat /proc/mdstat`, `lsblk`, `blkid` and so on). And a side note: forget about RAID5, never use it, it is like sitting on a barrel of gunpowder.

Comment: I'm running a system in 32-bit mode due to legacy software. It turns out that Linux can't efficiently manage the amount of memory the server has using PAE: https://flaterco.com/kb/PAE_slowdown.html. I was able to fix the issue by by enabling the VMSPLIT_2G configuration option and limiting the amount of addressable memory to 16G using the `mem=0x4000M` kernel boot parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running the system in 32-bit mode due to legacy software. It turns out that Linux can't efficiently manage the amount of memory the server has using PAE: [flaterco.com/kb/PAE_slowdown.html](https://flaterco.com/kb/PAE_slowdown.html).

I was able to fix the issue by by enabling the *VMSPLIT_2G* configuration option and limiting the amount of addressable memory to 16G using the *mem=0x4000M* kernel boot parameter.